# Button to start new Activity (Fragment?) from ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments

I am struggling to find a way to start a new Activity.
I am using this tutorial/example as the basis of a database:
http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sqlite-example/
and want to add a button to each item in the list view, to press for fuller details of each employee. I can add more data columns to the db, but cannot find  a way to start the new activity and pass the employees ID. (I can get the Position (row in List view), but this does not always match the ID, due to being able to delete records.

How would you suggest implementing this Button/Activity?

Comment: post at least the adapter code please, so we can know where are you struggling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add button to list_item then set onclick listener to the button inside the adapter

```
<Button  android:id="@+id/button1"/>
```

inside adapter:

```
     holder.go= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);


     holder.go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //start next activity here

        }
    });
```

Comment: That will (hopefully) react to the button, but I need to pass some data (the ID code of the Employee. NOT the row-position).

Comment: Employee emp=(Employee)employees.get(Position); will give you the whole object of that particular row then use intent to send data to next activity

Comment: While I don't want the whole data-set from the listView, you think that passing it all, and then just using the parts I need (the ID, to then call the Full Employee Details from the SQLite database) would work/be acceptable?

Comment: why don't you pass the the employee id like emp.getId() and put it oon intent and send it to next activity

Comment: I think using "holder" is what has made the difference. i haven't passed the data to new Activity yet, but my testing Toast has the correct numbers in. I have been trying this for some days, so I'm a little confused as to what I have and haven't tried, and why it hasnt' worked ... I shall now build the new Activity and see what happens ...

Comment: OK, I now have the new Activity displaying the ID (as a String), but cannot seem to call the database (or its Methods). 
I though this would work, but has a static/non-static clash.

     Employee displayEmployee = EmployeeDAO.getEmployee(intId);
     String displayName = displayEmployee.getName();